# Many to Many Data modelling in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, document-database, database

What is the best way of modelling such a relationship? I have a room collection and a user collection. A room can contain many users. A user can belong to many rooms.
I was thinking of inserting users of a room in an array (?) in the room collection. Is there a better way or is it incorrect altogether to do it the way I am doing it?

Comment: this is a typical case where SQL would be a better tool than NoSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is correct. MongoDB does not require a schema so you can store references to items from another collection in an item of one collection.

You can store an array of the ObjectIds from the `room` collection in the `user` collection to identify which rooms a person has joined. Likewise, you can store an array of the ObjectIds from the `user` collection in the `room` collection to identify what users have joined a room.

Your schemas would look similar to these:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  'name': String,
  rooms: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'RoomSchema' }]
});

var RoomSchema = new Schema({
  'name': String,
  'users': [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'UserSchema' }]
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Will this be a problem if the there are no limits on the number users that can join a specific room? For example if there are 200 users in a room, will that cause significant increase in document size?

Comment: It won't because you're only storing the IDs of the users and not the user data.

Answer (score 0):

It might look like:

```
{_id:"123", "type":"room", "users":[ 111, 222]}
{_id:"111", "type":"user", "room": [ 123, 456]}
```

Example add user in room:

```
db.test.update( { _id: "123" }, { $addToSet: {"users": 333 } } )
```

Example delete user from room:

```
db.test.update( { _id: "123" }, { $pullAll: { scores: [ 111, 222 ] }})
```